# Regular expression to match all ranges not between brackets or quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

> 'b1:b10 + sum(a1:a10, sum(b1:b21)) + a1 + "d23:d44" '

I want to extract all the ranges in the string (*a range is b1:b10 or a1*), so I use this regular expression:

> var rxRanges = new
>   RegExp('(([a-z]+[0-9]+[:][a-z]+[0-9]+)|([a-z]+[0-9]+))', 'gi');

This is returns all my ranges, so it returns: *[b1:b10, a1:a10, b1:b21, a1, d23:d44]*.

I now want to modify this regular expression to only search for the root ranges, in other words **return ranges not between specifically brackets or quotes**. So I am looking for this: *["b1:b10","a1"]*

Not sure how to approach this?

Comment: regular expressions cannot handle arbitrarily nested parentheses properly. Are you sure that this is even solvable using regexes?

Comment: Here is the answer to my question, credit to revo and user3218114: var re = /(?![^("]*[,)"])(([a-z]+[0-9]+[:][a-z]+[0-9]+)|([a-z]+[0-9]+))/gi;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*#Updated according to comments*

You can achieve that using a ***negative lookahead***:

```
/(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)(?![^(]*[,)])[a-z]\d+(:\w+)?/gi
```

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/zL6dW3/3)**

Comment: Assuming a1 were not in brackets it would need to be matched. So building on your answer, this is the solution: var re = /(?![^("]*[,)"])(([a-z]+[0-9]+[:][a-z]+[0-9]+)|([a-z]+[0-9]+))/gi;  thanks a mil!

Comment: Is it matching `a1` in `b1:b10 + sum(a1:a10, sum(b1:b21)) + a1 + "d23:d44`?

Comment: Correct, in the above example the desired output is: ["b1:b10","a1"]

Comment: @MarzSocks Are you using `match` method?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure I understand your questions context. Problem is solved in my first reply to revo though. :-)

Comment: @MarzSocks If the problem is solved then you should accept the answer or are you looking for more answers?

Comment: @MarzSocks also I replaced your newly mixed regex with mine in the demo page but it didn't match `a1` yet.

Answer (score 2):

Get the matched group from index 2

```
(^|[^(\"])([a-z]+[0-9]+:[a-z]+[0-9]+)
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/uL0fN8/8)

**Note:** I think there is no need to check for both end If needed then add `($|[^(\"])` in the the end of the above regex pattern.

---

Pattern explanation:

```
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    ^                        the beginning of the line/string
   |                        OR
    [^(\"]                   any character except: '(', '"'
  )                        end of \1

  (                        group and capture to \2:
    [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more times)
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more times)
    :                        ':'
    [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more times)
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more times)
  )                        end of \2
```

Sample code:

```
var str = 'b1:b10 + sum(a1:a10, sum(b1:b21)) + (a1) + "d23:d44" ';
var re = /(^|[^(\"])([a-z]+[0-9]+:[a-z]+[0-9]+)/gi;
var found = str.match(re);

alert(found);
```

Comment: Thanks - you are on the right track, but lets assume a1 is not in brackets, then it too needs to be included, how would you tweak this?

Comment: please share your input string and how you will distinguish it from others as per your rule.

Comment: Input string: 'b1:b10 + sum(a1:a10, sum(b1:b21)) + a1 + "d23:d44"' the desired match should be b1:b10, a1

Comment: so you want to match `a1` as well?

Comment: Yes! Any range not in brackets or quotes. a1 can be considered a range.

Comment: This fails on `sum( b1:b21)`, `" d23:d44"`, ...[example](http://regex101.com/r/iP6dL0/1), but maybe something like that wouldn't appear, so then it's fine to use it.

Comment: `(^|[^(\":]\s+)(([a-z]+[0-9]+:?)+)` will fix it. Just `\s+` is added.

Comment: I am finding your latest answer includes a leading + sign, so the output is: b1:b10, + a1

Comment: This `/(^|[^(\":])([a-z]+[0-9]+(:[a-z]+[0-9]+)?)/gi` is working fine for me. It returns `["b1:b10", " a1"]` in firefox for input string `b1:b10 + sum(a1:a10, sum(b1:b21)) + a1 + "d23:d44"`

Comment: Indeed, however if you did not have a leading space i.e. 'b1:b10+sum(a1:a10,sum(b1:b21))+a1+"d23:d44")' you will get ["b1:b10", "+a1"]

Comment: Solution found, thanks for all your help, see comment to revo!

Comment: The following expression does exactly what I need: var re = /(?![^("]*[,)"])(([a-z]+[0-9]+[:][a-z]+[0-9]+)|([a-z]+[0-9]+))/gi;